# A comprehensive list of words in Chinese?

Tags: data-request

I'm trying to find a Chinese (and also French) word list, similar to this one for English: [https://www.mit.edu/~ecprice/wordlist.10000](https://www.mit.edu/%7Eecprice/wordlist.10000)

All I'm finding are 100-500 word lists. Anyone know a comprehensive list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MDBG dictonary has a [downloadable text file](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=cedict) in csv format containing 200,000+ Chinese words in alphabetical order. There is also a (smaller) version with French word definitions of Chinese words.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any ready-made word list either, but here you can [generate a word list from the corpus](http://cql.corpora.uni-leipzig.de/bonito/run.cgi/wordlist_form).

At first just adjust an options and click `Make word list`:

[image]

Then you can save a word list to CSV, TSV or XML by choosing `Save` on the left-side menu:

[image]